# Hazelcast .net client deserilization issue

Tags: java, c#, serialization, hazelcast

I try to use custom serilization at Hazelcast. In documentation, there is an example for Java. I add it my code. On the other hand, I have a .net client, so I need to deseriliaze it but I cannot code read and write methods. My sample .net client code here, how can I use it?

```
public class TestModelSerializer : IStreamSerializer<TestModel> {

    public void Destroy() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int GetTypeId()
    {
        return 158;
    }

    public TestModel Read(IObjectDataInput input) {
        ?????
         //Here I cannot solved....
    }

    public void Write(IObjectDataOutput output,TestModel obj) {
        ?????
         //Here I cannot solved....
    }
}
```

On Java side code is:

```
public static class TestModelXmlSerializer implements StreamSerializer<TestModel> {


    public int getTypeId() {
        return 158;
    }


    public void write(ObjectDataOutput out, TestModel object ) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder( bos );
        encoder.writeObject( object );
        encoder.close();
        out.write( bos.toByteArray() );
    }


    public TestModel read( ObjectDataInput in ) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) in;
        XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder( inputStream );
        return (TestModel) decoder.readObject();
    }


    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: The serialized binary data should be deserialized on .Net side but you use java XML encoder. The generated xml can be hard to process on .Net. You should prefer something that you can handle on .Net.

Comment: Ok, but how I can do? Streams throw exceptions so what I write that methods? For example this throw exception.

`public TestModel Read(IObjectDataInput input) {
            StreamReader inputStream = (StreamReader)input;
            XmlSerializer decoder = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestModel));
            return (TestModel)decoder.Deserialize(inputStream);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast custom serializer should use a compatible data format in order to be used from various platforms such as .Net.

Java XmlEncoder/XmlDecoder is not compatible with .Net XmlSerializer xml format so it is not suitable for this task. If you ignore the performance you may use json instead. For example, you can use GSON on java and json.net on .Net which share same data format.

The best approach is whether to use the custom serialization API directly or delegate a high performance serialization library of your choice.